# Python - List Comparison/matching

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have two lists - list 1 has part number (not unique), order number (blank), job number (blank), color, and quantity fields. List 2 has part number (unique), order number, and job number fields. I need to fill in the order number and job number on list 1, based on the information from list 2 (by matching the part #)

**List 1 (mainlist)**

Part # (BM001),
Order # (EMPTY),
Job # (EMPTY),
Color (Black),
Quantity (2)

Part # (BM001),
Order # (EMPTY),
Job # (EMPTY),
Color (Red),
Quantity (4)

Part # (BM002),
Order # (EMPTY),
Job # (EMPTY),
Color (Green),
Quantity (5)

**List 2 (valueslist)**

Part # (BM001),
Order # (26534),
Job # (75)

Part # (BM002),
Order # (26535),
Job # (76)

**Desired Results (I only need list 1, with order # and job # filled in)**

Part # (BM001),
Order # (26534),
Job # (75),
Color (Black),
Quantity (2)

Part # (BM001), Order # (26534), Job # (75), Color (Red), Quantity (4)

Part # (BM002), Order # (26535), Job # (76), Color (Green), Quantity (5)

Here is my code so far (see below) but it is not matching the data properly. I'm assuming there is an easier (and more efficient) way of doing this but at this point I am stuck.

Note: This is within Dynamo/Revit, which utilizes Python to access the Revit API.

Thank you in advance.

```
dataEnteringNode = IN
mainlist=IN[0]
valueslist=IN[1]
outlist=[]

for i in mainlist:
    #Part #
    item0=i[0]

    #Order #
    item1=""

    #Job #
    item2=""

    #Color
    item3=i[3]

    #QTY.
    item4=i[4]


    for j in valueslist:
        #Job # and Task #
        if ( i[0] == j[0] ):
            item1=j[1]
            item2=j[2]


    #Write Data
    outlist.append(item0)
    outlist.append(item1)
    outlist.append(item2)
    outlist.append(item3)
    outlist.append(item4)


#Assign your output to the OUT variable.
OUT = outlist
```

Comment: What exactly is in your lists? Lists do not have "fields" in Python, so please be specific.

Comment: Why use `#Part ... item0=i[0]` instead of naming the variable `part` and removing the comment?

Answer (score 1):

the easiest is using python dict, then convert it to list manually

```
data = {}
for i in mainlist:

    data[i[0]] = {'color' : i[3], 'quantity' : i[4]}

for j in valuelist:

    if data.get(i[0]):
        data[i[0]] = {**data[i[0]], 'order' : i[1], 'job' : i[2]}
    else:
        data[i[0]] = {'order' : i[1], 'job' : i[2]}
```